# unable to login in modx manager after migration

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I'm using ModX Revo 2.6
I moved my site from another hosting and it's work fine, but now I can't log in into manager.
I triple checked that password is correct, I tried to reset it via email, even change it in DB - nothing helped, I still get the message that login or password is incorrect.
Also, [here](https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/security/troubleshooting-security/resetting-a-user-password-manually) is the API script to reset password, but it returns me that user does not exist.
Also when I try to reset it via email it doesn't change in DB, even I still got the message with new one.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I end up reinstalling clear version and then merge all db tables except users and user_attributes and now I can enter with account I made wile install.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean up **/core/cache/** folder, and set 777 to it.

Check database setting in **/core/config/config.inc.php** Make sure that all settings is correct (check all uppercase places in my example!)

```
$database_type = 'mysql';
$database_server = 'localhost';
$database_user = 'USERNAME';
$database_password = 'PASSWORD';
$database_connection_charset = 'utf8';
$dbase = 'DBNAME';
$table_prefix = 'modx_';
$database_dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8';
```

In addition, check absolute folders in **/core/config/config.inc.php**

For example:

```
if (!defined('MODX_CORE_PATH')) {
    $modx_core_path= '/absolute/path/to/your/website.com/core/';
    define('MODX_CORE_PATH', $modx_core_path);
}
```

Also, you can reinstall MODx at new server. Download last version, upload to server (rewrite all files) and go to your-website.com/setup and follow instructions. **Don't forget to make backup.**